# list of hive tables in a local directory

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Local directory it is used to store the hive table data.

**I need to list all tables which are using Local directory .**

These tables (managed tables) are stored in hive Default DB , this DB allows to store Data in other Local directories .

My Local directory : /abc/efg/data/

Table data is Stored in sub folders like  123 , 456,789 etc

For table xyz location is /abc/efg/data/123 , PQR location is /abc/efg/data/456 like that.

I am trying to use

**hive -e " show tables " > All_tables**  *list all tables and redirect to a file*

For each line(each table) in All_tables

**hive -e " desc formatted $line " | grep '/abc/efg/data/' >> Tables_My_local_dir**

but it will result some performance issue as i have 6000 tables in DB .

please help me to list all tables which are using Local directory with a best performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the rule

HADOOP TABLES ARE DIRECTORIES

I have created a shell script to do the below steps.

Step 1. Find all the directories which are not being modified since last 14 days .

Step 2 . Separate real tables and real folders 2.1execute "desc $dir_name "

2.2 based on return status($？) redirect $dir_name to two files(one for real tables and other for directories )

Now I have the required tables in a file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you wanted to list table and its corresponding location information by extracting it from the **desc formatted** command for managed tables in default database.

If my understanding is correct, I suggest you to go with querying the Hive Meta-store, provided its an externally configured one and you have necessary permissions to fetch the same information

**Query on meta-store:**

```
SELECT T.TBL_NAME AS TABLE_NAME,S.LOCATION AS LOCATION FROM TBLS T LEFT JOIN SDS S ON T.SD_ID=S.SD_ID WHERE T.TBL_TYPE='MANAGED_TABLE' AND T.DB_ID=1 ;
```

**note:** in the query, DB_ID for default database is 1

**Output:**

```
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | LOCATION                                                   |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| sample     | hdfs://********:8020/user/hive/warehouse/sample |
...
```

.